Make RGB java.awt.Color lighter
Can I take a java.awt.Color, turn it into a HSL color, and make it a notch lighter or darker — that is, increase or decrease the L value by, say ten points (obviously, within the 0 to 100 range)?
If so, how?
The less code the better. If Apache or Guava can help, feel free to use them
I could use HSB instead (see the code below), but it doesn't produce the same results (e.g. increasing B by ten is not the same as increasing L by ten)
package demos.color;

import java.awt.Color;

public class ColorUtils {
        public static Color brighterBy(Color color, float factor) {
        return adjustBrightness(color, factor);
    }

    public static Color darkerBy(Color color, float factor) {
        return adjustBrightness(color, -factor);
    }

    private static Color adjustBrightness(Color color, float factor) {
        float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), null);
        hsb[2] = Math.min(Math.max(hsb[2] + factor, 0.0f), 1.0f);
        return new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color originalColor = new Color(184, 207, 229);
        Color lighterColor = brighterBy(originalColor, 0.2f);
        Color darkerColor = darkerBy(originalColor, 0.2f);

        System.out.println("Original Color: " + originalColor);
        System.out.println("Lighter Color: " + lighterColor);
        System.out.println("Darker Color: " + darkerColor);
    }
}


Check out: HSL Color

The Java Color class has a brighter and darker method.  Do these methods not work for you?

@GilbertLeBlanc no, they don't. I can't specify the degree

See also HSB vs HSL vs HSV.

@Heneh,  I can't specify the degree - The HSL Color class does allow you to specify thedegree. Does is not solve your problem? Either way don't you think you should comment so people know if the problem is solved or not?

@camickr I haven't yet had a chance to check it out. I just came to my workplace

@camickr The issue I see is the terms "shade" and "tone" are introduced but never properly defined (I guess they just relate to decreasing or increasing luminance respectively, but I had to look into the source code for that). I would be more comfortable if you stuck with the terms of the acronym itself (hue, shade, luminance). Secondly, hsl[0], hsl[1], hsl[2] are not as readable as having fields hue, saturation, luminance. Thirdly, adjustX() methods do two things: adjust a HSL color component and convert the HSL color to java.awt.Color

@Heneh the terms "shade" and "tone" are introduced but never properly defined - not sure what you mean. They are defined to make the color darker or lighter which is what your question asked.  How this is done is not relevant to the method name. Also, the demo code shows examples of how the shade/tone methods work. ...are not as readable as having fields... - feel free to rewrite the code. That format was used because of the algorithm I found to do the conversion used that format.

In any case, you still haven't answered the question if you problem is solved or not. If it does, you are welcome. If it doesn't, well at least I tried. Don't forget to post your solution when you find one so other can benefit as well.

@camickr yes, it technically solves it. You can post. Thank you
